# Setting up NSCA in Docker Alpine image for passive nagios check

Tags: docker, nagios, alpine-linux

In the Alpine linux package site https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages
NSCA packages are yet to get added. Is there an alternative to setup NSCA in Alpine Linux for passive-check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no package for it, you can always build it yourself.

```
FROM alpine AS builder

ARG NSCA_VERSION=2.9.2

RUN apk update && apk add build-base build-base gcc wget git

RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/nagios/nsca-$NSCA_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf nsca-$NSCA_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN cd nsca-$NSCA_VERSION&& ./configure && make all
RUN ls -lah nsca-$NSCA_VERSION/src
RUN mkdir -p /dist/bin && cp nsca-$NSCA_VERSION/src/nsca /dist/bin
RUN mkdir -p /dist/etc && cp nsca-$NSCA_VERSION/sample-config/nsca.cfg /dist/etc

FROM alpine

COPY --from=builder /dist/bin/nsca /bin/
COPY --from=builder /dist/etc/nsca.cfg /etc/
```

Since this is using multiple stages, your resulting image will not contain development files and will still be small.